# Creating a playlist with LWJGL and OpenAL

Tags: java, lwjgl, openal

I'd like to know how to create a playlist for the music in my games. I use LWJGL, and know a bit of OpenAL, however I can't figure out how to test for when a song is over. I want to be able to play one song after another, and I want to do that without hardcoding a timer for each song.